# Does reversing a clip of Obama saying "Yes We Can" become "Thank you, Satan"?

Tags: barack-obama, backmasking

A friend of mine forwarded me [Obama Yes We Can = Thank you Satan (when reversed)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqALdkTArqs), a video claiming that an audio clip of Obama saying "Yes We Can", when reversed, says "Thank you, Satan".

Is this video accurate? That is, has any manipulation been done to the audio of Obama and the cheering crowd, apart from merely reversing it? I'm especially suspicious about the cheering crowd at the end, because the "Thank" there seems to have a "th" sound, unlike when Obama was saying it. I assume they'd fake the cheering crowd reversed rather than Obama reversed, because it'd be easier to impersonate a crowd than impersonate Obama.

Examples of people discussing the "Thank you Satan" meme, but not necessarily this video: [1](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/unreasonablefaith/2010/09/obama-yes-we-can-thank-you-satan/), [2](http://beforeitsnews.com/obama/2012/10/obama-yes-we-can-thank-you-satan-video-2445032.html), [3](http://www.davidicke.com/forum/showthread.php?t=58653), [4](http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/chat/2215392/posts)

Comment: And this would apply only to Obama, and not to anyone else saying "yes, we can"? What does your spider-sense tell you?

Comment: @Mawg in theory, him being reversed and other people being reversed should give the same result, but I haven't empirically examined it. if his voice being reversed gave a different sound to other people being reversed, that'd be a revelation (pun intended).

Comment: This needs to be focused on something factual. What reversing a sentence sounds like is an opinion.